# ¿Como separar nombres y apellidos de una cadena?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito lo siguiente, me dicen que tengo que hacer un store procedure que me haga una consulta y me retorne unos datos para generar un archivo .csv separado por comas, me entregaron un archivo excel como ejemplo de lo que debería llevar el .csv , pero tengo un problema para conseguir unos datos.... Como pueden observar en la imagen si la columna 2 es = a 2 el nombre completo lo separa por apellido 1, apellido 2, nombre 1, nombre 2 y si es = a 1 deja ese espacio en blanco

Ahora la cuestión es que como separar eso en la consulta ya que el terraz o sea la razón social viene en una cadena o sea no viene separado, como validaría y separaría los datos ?

[image: Esta es la imagen]

```
declare @RazonSocial varchar (200)
set @RazonSocial = 'MANQUILLO MAZABUEL ANGEL FREDY'
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(@RazonSocial, 1, charindex(' ', @RazonSocial)) Apellido1,
SUBSTRING(@RazonSocial, charindex(' ', @RazonSocial), len(@RazonSocial))Apellido2,
SUBSTRING(@RazonSocial, charindex(' ', @RazonSocial), len(@RazonSocial))Nombre1,
SUBSTRING(@RazonSocial, charindex(' ', @RazonSocial), len(@RazonSocial)) Nombre2
```

ESA CONSULTA ME TRAE SOLO EL APELLIDO1 BIEN DE RESTO ES IGUAL

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: Podrías usar como filtro los espacios en blanco y utilizar algún tipo de `split`.´Aún así sería excelente si publicas lo que has tratado hasta ahora :)

Comment: Mira de nuevo el detalle de la pregunta la consulta que hice pero solo me funciona para el apellido1

Comment: Este tipo de procesos es bastante complicado y no conozco ninguna opción que sea 100% segura. El problema se presenta porque la cantidad de nombres y apellidos puede variar  pero también varía con los nombres compuestos. Además, está el problema de las personas morales que no tienen nombre y apellido, sólo razón social.

Comment: La mejor opción es pedir la información limpia y de no ser posible, es importante  que haya una revisión manual para confirmar que la división se haya hecho de forma correcta.